# Making PostgreSQL query more DRY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at),
  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('low')))
  ) as food_insecurity,

  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('low')))
  ) as motivation                               
  FROM survey_results
  GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at);
```

Query works very nice but there is a lot of repetition. I'm thinking how can I make it more DRY? Here is the sql fiddle that You can use to experiments:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/746c9/5

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it more readable is to extract `scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}`:

```
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at),
  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub.food in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub.food in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub.food in('low')))
  ) as food_insecurity,
  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub.motivation in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub.motivation in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub.motivation in('low')))
  ) as motivation                               
  FROM survey_results
 JOIN LATERAL (SELECT scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}',
                      scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}'
              ) sub(motivation, food)   ON true
 GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/GVZ16669)**

Another step could be [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tablefunc.html) or some sort of pivoting to avoid declaring `high``medium`\`low` 3 times.

**EDIT:**

Version that use `json_object_agg`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM survey_results
    JOIN LATERAL (SELECT scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}',
                         scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}'
                 ) s1(motivation, food) ON true
)
SELECT  cte.created_at::DATE
       ,MIN(s3.motivation)::json AS motivation
       ,MIN(s3.food_insecurity)::json AS food_insecurity
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(lvl, cnt_motivation)::text
                         ,JSON_OBJECT_AGG(lvl, cnt_food)::text
                   FROM(SELECT sub2.lvl
                            ,COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub2.lvl = sub.motivation))
                            ,COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (sub2.lvl = sub.food))
                        FROM cte sub
                        CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('high'),
                                         ('medium'), ('low')) AS sub2(lvl)
                        GROUP BY sub2.lvl
                       ) s2(lvl,cnt_motivation, cnt_food)
                  ) s3(motivation,food_insecurity)
          ON true
GROUP BY cte.created_at::DATE;
```

**[Rextester Demo 2](http://rextester.com/ISUQ76437)**

Comment: @MateuszUrbański If you want you could experiment with **[Demo](http://rextester.com/TOI49513)**, you need to find a way to build JSON with dynamic keys. I guess it is possible, but unfortunately I don't have time to make it work now.